# Production flask app running in parallel with main program on a Raspberry pi

Tags: python, flask

I have built a system around a Raspberry pi that continuously takes images, runs some computer vision analyses on the images, and reads some variables from a sensor.

Image files are saved on board as are analysis results and sensor data (in sqlite databases).

Now, I need to present collected data (images and analyses results) in real time. I am doing this with a Flask app. Currently, I am running the main program and the flask app from one script using threading, which seem to work okay. But, how do I do this with a production server, so that the app can be accessed from other computers on the same network as the pi?

Here's how I am currently running the main program and the webapp in "parallel":

```
# Data
import time
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

# Webapp
import threading
from flask import Flask
import random as rand


def databaseSetup():
    # Initialize SQLite database connection and create table to store sensor data
    connSensor = sqlite3.connect('sensorVariables.db')
    cSensor = connSensor.cursor()
    cSensor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensorVariables
            (timestamp TEXT, temperature REAL, pressure REAL, humidity REAL)''')
    return connSensor, cSensor

def main():
    connSensor, cSensor = databaseSetup()
    i = 0

    while True:
        print("Still running main worker: ", i)
    
        temperature = rand.randint(12,25)
        pressure = rand.randint(1020, 1200)
        humidity =  rand.randint(40,80)

        # Get current timestamp
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        # Insert data into env database
        cSensor.execute("INSERT INTO sensorVariables VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (timestamp, temperature, pressure, humidity))
        connSensor.commit()
        print("Sensor variables saved")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(5)


######## WEBAPP ########
app = Flask(__name__)

def runApp():
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # connect to the sqlite database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('sensorVariables.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # retrieve the latest weather data from the database
    c.execute('SELECT temperature, humidity, pressure, timestamp FROM sensorVariables ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1')
    latest_data = c.fetchone()
    temperature = latest_data[0]
    humidity = latest_data[1]
    pressure = latest_data[2]
    timestamp = latest_data[3]

    # close the database connection
    conn.close()
    return f'Time: {timestamp}, Temperature: {temperature}, Humidity: {humidity}, Pressure: {pressure}'


######## RUN ########
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
       t1 = threading.Thread(target=runApp).start()
       t2 = threading.Thread(target=main).start()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to separate the two applications, which I suggest you manage via [systemctl](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-systemctl-manage-services).

an example of how you can configure your .service file to control a flask application with systemctl:

```
[Unit]
Description=flask service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bbadmin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=<yout_working_dir>
ExecStart=/<gunicorn_installation_path>/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 <...other start params>
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

an example of how you can configure your .service file to control a python script with systemctl:

```
[Unit]
Description=py script
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/<python3_installation_path>/python3 <main_file_path.py>
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

other useful links:

- [manage python scripts with systemctl](https://medium.com/codex/setup-a-python-script-as-a-service-through-systemctl-systemd-f0cc55a42267)
- [manage python flask app with systemctl](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-a-flask-application-as-a-service-with-systemd)